# Is it possible to connect to MongoDB from Istio proxy without allowing invalid certificates and direct connection?

Tags: mongodb, ssl, istio, istio-gateway, istio-sidecar

I have a question regarding configuring the Istio proxy to connect to MongoDB without making any modifications to the client configuration. Currently, the client connects to MongoDB using the following connection string:

mongodb://@HOST/db?ssl=True&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true&directConnection=true

However, I would like to set up the Istio proxy in a way that allows me to connect to MongoDB using a simpler connection string:

mongodb://@HOST/db

without explicitly specifying the use of TLS.

Is it possible to achieve this configuration with Istio? If so, what steps do I need to follow?

Thank you for your assistance.

I tried this https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-tls-origination/ but it failed, connection is not going

Comment: TLS is disabled by default. I think if you like to use TLS/SSL then you must specify it in the connection string.